# Client/Agent pulled the plug following pre-employment check failure - UK based

Tags: united-kingdom

Hopefully I'll benefit for some sound advice up here and/or guidance.

I was offered a role and the starting date was finalised and agreed. I started the onboarding process and submitted all the documents required. Every document was genuine - some were accredited by the relevant official bodies in the relevant jurisdictions and all "gaps" on CV explained and backed up by further documentations. I was also contacted by the CFO (who had interviewed me) couple of days before the original starting date "welcoming" me on board and providing the log in credentials. A day prior to the call the company had arranged to send the tech equipment to my house - which was a clear indication that all was supposedly clear so far.

However due to some technicality and delay in them processing their data, the start date was pushed back for a couple of days later (but at my expense towards loss of income). The contracts for the original date were sent to me, signed by all parties and sent back to them. Following the change in the starting date, the amended contracts were sent, signed by all and sent back.
However a day prior to starting I received a message that Compliance will not be pursing with my employment and that there was no longer any further arrangement by the client due to a failure in my pre-employment screening check. Since then I have been trying to get to the bottom of this to find out what could have possibly caused the failure but to date, all I am hearing is a deafening silence!

I am very annoyed by this malpractice and considering the possibility of legal action where applicable. Do I have any valid grounds so far? Any clues, links to further information please? Thank you.

Comment: This is very recent, the decision and outcome was towards the latter part of last week. And since yesterday, I am still on the case to get an answer before I consider the next step. And I am smelling something rather fishy about their decision. I also reached out to the third party data management company hired to perform the check but heard nothing yet.

Comment: They didn't ask you to pay anything to get the 'equipment' delivered to your house, did they?

Comment: No they didn't. But this is part of the protocol now due to the work from home/hybrid arrangement.

Comment: I asked before there are scams involving fake jobs where the applicant is asked to purchase equipment and be reimbursed later, and the equipment, of course, never arrives.

Comment: "Cybercrooks target students with fake job opportunities" - The Register (UK) [today 22 March 2022](https://www.theregister.com/2022/03/29/student_scams/) Even if they don't take your money they get a nice lot of personal data, copies of documents, etc.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes I also thought of the above too. I think Data is definitely more lucrative to them. They also wanted to me consent to some further checks which would involve some unknown overseas third party contractors looking into my background etc. I have absolutely nothing to hide as my DBS was clean along with credit/non-credit background. I think the fact that I challenged them (by seeking details of those contractors) might have "put them off". Don't know!

Comment: Sadly this does look dodgy. Do some checking on the Companies House web site; it doesn't cost anything, and you'll soon get an impression whether the company really exists or not - unless of course they've stolen the identity of a reputable company.

Comment: Although this crossed my mind, I know both the agency and the company are genuine. They are relatively well know in the UK at least. I also did a background check on the CFO and he's pretty legit. I am just very intrigued about what could have prompted the failure that's all, considering I've never had any run-ins with the law in any shape, way or form. But thanks for your thought! :)

Comment: The UK has a wonderful organization called the Citizens Advice Bureau which gives you help, including basic legal advice, in situations like this. I would start by contacting them.

Comment: @DJClayworth, Of course, the CAB. Thanks for the reminder. Thank you also for the edited text! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have any valid grounds so far?

Basically, no. The company made a decision to terminate your employment, something they are perfectly entitled to do so long as it was not based on a [protected characteristic](https://www.equalityhumanrights.com/en/equality-act/protected-characteristics).

They should pay you for whatever the notice period specified in your contract was, but other than that you have no claim.

Comment: Thanks Philip. I was thinking at the very least that I am compensated for loss of income from the scheduled starting date...but up until when normally I am not sure. But even then, I would have to prove they acted with incompetence right? (hence why I also need to know the cause of failure). The duration of the initial contract (it was a temp position and all this is via an agency) was for 6 months at least.

Comment: It's time to move on. You didn't get the job, find another one.

Comment: Noted, thanks for this. In terms of the data they processed, do I have the right, under Data Protection Act to request them to destroy and subsequently request confirmation they did so, under FOI Act? Thanks

Comment: We're not your legal advice; talk to your lawyer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Both parties had signed a contract; in UK law that cannot be ignored. "Not being hired" in this case is equivalent to giving immediate notice that the employer intends to terminate the contract, so they are still liable for whatever notice period was specified in that contract (maybe minus a day, need a lawyer for that one)

Comment: Thank you both for your input on this. I'll see where this leads to especially once I find out the reason(s) for the failure.

Comment: UPDATE: I just received an email from the recruitment agency informing me that because they were unable to conduct an overseas criminality check (presumably they couldn't find a suitable local agent), the client decided not to proceed! I find it rather unfair but it is what it is. Anyway I just wanted to give you guys the complete picture.